# Turn on the validation XSD 1.1 in Intellij IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, xsd-validation

is any way how to turn on the validation of XSD version 1.1 in Intellij IDEA instead of default 1.0? As I know to be able to validate against version 1.1 the processor should just take -xsdversion:1.1, but I don't see any configuration point in IDE how I can set it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This feature was added in Intellij 15

Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Schemas and DTDs -> Default XML Schemas

Comment: IntelliJ 2017.1: I was able to select the XML Schema 1.1 but when trying to validate my files, I get validation errors in the schema itself, in the file: IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.1\lib\idea.jar!\standardSchemas\XMLSchema-1_1\XMLSchema.xsd

Comment: me too.. so can someone confirm 1.1 support is broken in IJ? I don't want to waste my time trying to get it to work - however, I really want it to work

Comment: If it only worked! IntelliJ 2017.2: Still getting validation errors in the internal schema file _...\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.2.5\lib\idea.jar!\standardSchemas\XMLSchema.xsd._  But is the problem the schema or the internal schema parser?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone will stuck with this issue, please be aware that this functionality is missing in the Intellij IDEA so far, I've discussed it on the JetBrains forum: http://devnet.jetbrains.com/message/5511591#5511591 and created a feature request for it, so we'll be waiting for it in the following releases :)